# ImportError: No module named 'numpy' - on mac

Tags: python, numpy

I have just started with python, sorry for the very basic question. I am aware that there are similar questions BUT after having installed Python 3.5 I used homebrew for the suited numpy version with:

```
brew install homebrew/python/numpy --with-python3
```

as recommended in some answer. Nevertheless, I still get the ImportError: No module named 'numpy' error - what more can I do?

Comment: Maybe you have multiple Python installations and you are not running the right one?

Comment: How can I check that on OSX 10.9.2? python -V and python --version did not work out in my terminal

Comment: in the python interpreter: `import sys, sys.executable`
You can also try to write `which python` in the terminal.

Comment: >>> import sys
>>> sys.executable
'/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.5/bin/python3.5'

So I don't know...